# Dynamically select tests to run with webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, webdriver

I'm a tester working with automation and recently looking into webdriver and I get the idea with pageObjects and how to run tests with Nunit for example.
My problem is that I don't want to run tests in a predefined order. The GUI-automation solution we currently have uses ModelBasedTesting tool GraphWalker to generate the testsequence at execution and I would like to continue with that approach.

It works like this in short: A graph contains action- and verificationsteps and some logic to determine how to "walk the graph". Each step represent a method to be executed in webdriver.

I could of course make a lot of methods and call them one by one, but then I would not have the nice support of a testing framework like Nunit or the structure of PageObjects.

What I (think) I would like is:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class LoginTest : TestFixtureBase
{
    [Test]
    public void e_test1()
    {
        loginPage = PageBase.GetInstance<Login>(driver, "Title");                
        accountHome = loginPage.MainLogin(username, password);
        Assert.IsTrue(accountHome.UserLoggedIn(),"fail");
    }
    [Test]
    public void v_test1()
    {
        loginPage = accountHome.LogOut();
        Assert.IsTrue(loginPage.UserLoggedOut(), "Fail");
    }
    .
    .
    .
    [Test]
    public void e_testN()
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

And then when i run the graph it gives me "e_test2" as a first step and the magic code runs e_test2(). Next step is "v_test1"  so that test is executed.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Update:
I've tried the TestCaseSource attribute and got it working, but only when it runs the graph prior the test and returns the complete sequence. I'm looking for a way to execute one step at the time "online". 
This works:

```
    [Test, TestCaseSource("RunModel")]
    public void LoginAndOut(string method)
    {
        object obj = this.GetType().InvokeMember(method, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, this, null);
    }

    public string[] RunModel()
    {
        List<string> methods = new List<string>();
        while (Model.graphWalker.HasNextStep())
        {
            methods.Add(Model.graphWalker.GetNextStep().ToString());
        }
        return methods.ToArray();
    }
```

But I would like to accomplish something like:

```
    while (Model.graphWalker.HasNextStep())
        {   //Get next method from GraphWalker Soap-service.
            nextMethodToRun = Model.graphWalker.GetNextStep().ToString());
            //handle Method result, if ok continue.
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up on NUnit and found the solution with Gallio/MbUtnit and DynamicTestFactory. 
works just as intended.

```
    [DynamicTestFactory]
    public IEnumerable<Test> LoginAndOut() 
    {
        string method;
        while (Model.graphWalker.HasNextStep())
        {
            method=Model.graphWalker.GetNextStep().ToString();
            if (method == string.Empty)
                break;
            yield return new TestCase(method, () =>
                {
                    object obj = this.GetType().InvokeMember(method, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, this, null);
                });
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create an adapter between GraphWalker and your code - parse the path created by GraphWalker and launch the required test methods accordingly, i.e. create an instance of your test class (it couldn't be abstract then) and invoke the required methods.

Comment: I still would like for NUnit to run the tests to get the testresult data "for free". If I let my console-app run the tests (via GraphWalker) I would have to make my own reporting tool and can't use the other nice features of NUnit.